# реализация табов на странице vue js

Tags: vue.js

Сейчас практикуюсь с вью, дали задание на стажировке: реализовать табы - группу кнопок с выводом контента.
Если кнопка голубая - значит контент отображается (т.е. если все кнопки голубые -значит отображается весь контент), если кнопка красная - контент скрывается. [image: vue]
Вроде бы все понятно, но обязали реализовать это по следующему шаблону

```js
data() {
return {
groupsState: {
content1: true,
content2: true,
content3: true,
content4: true,
content5: true
}
};
```

```html
<group-selector>
  <group-selector-item v-model="groupsState.content1">контент 1</group-selector-item>
</group-selector>

<content1 v-if="groupsState.content1></content1>
<content2></content2> 
<content3></content3>
,.....
```

`group-selector`- как я понял, компонент для группы табов, `group-selector-item` - компонент для отдельного таба

При этом я должен использовать input="$emit('input', $event.target.value).
Честно скажу, увидев задачку, я не понял, что от меня требуется.
Выполнить надо в течение дня, спросить не у кого. Стажировка первый день, опыта у меня очень мало, не был готов к такому, если честно...

Помогите пожалуйста сообразить, что от меня требуется. Буду очень благодарен!!!

Comment: библиотеки попросили не использовать

Comment: Вы бы добавили в конце вопроса код с компонентами, которые уже удалось реализовать.

Comment: мне дали задачку чисто для практики вчистую...ничего не готово. В компоненты с контентом можно пока хоть просто заголовок положить. Задачу пока не решал, пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: group-selector, group-selector-item - чисто пока названия просто. Компоненты также не готовы. Потому я и задаюсь вопросом что и как

Comment: `Че тут думать? Решать надо!` © *препод по физике* https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: спасибо за наводку со слотами! решаю!